# regext match all occurences but stop at string

Tags: regex

I'm getting headache with regex.... again....

Having the text: //Edit1: I had to change the text since I'm not starting with the values each line

```
lorem ipsum 1 $input_value sample
lorem ispum 2 "$input_notvalue"
lorem ipsum 3 helloworld $input_theme samplemeh
<script>$input_value</script>
```

I want to match any occurence of "$input" and return the whole word where this "$input" is occuring, but want to exclude the results within "script" and "/script".

My achievement: `\$input\w*` // EDIT1: Update:

https://regex101.com/r/BM87xA/4/

It would also be okay to stop with the search on the first occurence of the word script...

I'm thankful for any help....

Cheers,
S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find all $input_xxx, except the ones included in `<script>`-Tags.

I believe, the closest possible solution is the following:

```
/^(?!<script>).*?(\$input_\w+).*?(?!<\/script>).*?/sgim
```

https://regex101.com/r/BM87xA/14/

In my opinion, it is not possible to create a regex with postive match surrounded by "self-searching" negative matches. You would need a marker character (like new-line, end of line or another rarely used) before and after the script tags. The following expression schows the problem with the search, not using sticky marker charakters.

```
/(?!<script>).*?(\$input_\w+).*?(?!<\/script>)/sgimy
```

https://regex101.com/r/BM87xA/14/

I added some other test cases to show, how it behaves in different cases.

If you are free to choose the pattern to search for, it is much easier to select a more unique pattern. If you want to ensure that simply the code inside the script does not get corrupted, you could easily chose "forbidden" or uncritical stuff like comment-signs. E.g. your match pattern looks like

```
/*input_sometext*/
```

and in your regex you search for

```
/\/\*input_\w+\*\/
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to match lines beginning with the word $input use **^**

```
^\$input\w+
```

You could also used negative look ahead assertion that would match for lines beginning with word $input but not script

```
^(?!<script>)\$input\w+
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunately I had to update my regex sample text. I'm not starting with those search-values each line: https://regex101.com/r/BM87xA/4

Answer (score 0):

if you're using python this is probably what you need :

```
text = """
$input_value
$input_notvalue
$input_theme
<script>$input_value</script>
 """

pattern = '\$input\w+'
result = re.findall(pattern, text)
print result
```

result is a list of elements where $input exist:

```
['$input_value', '$input_notvalue', '$input_theme', '$input_value']
```

Comment: thanks! I'm using javascript and in my special case I need a real regex since it's processing steps via a while loop.